# Can someone help me identify this font please?

Tags: fonts, text

I don't know what the curves on the edges of the letters are called, and I can't seem to find a similar one. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The curves on the edges of the letters are called 'serifs'.

I can't find an exact match, but this looks to be a custom edit of the [Circensis](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/rmu/circensis/) font.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to find it, but I don't see the same fonts, I think it is edited font from "" [Miss Scarlett Plain](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontmesa/miss-scarlett/plain/)

[image]